# how can i drop the **needlessness** tables which generated automatically by metadata in JPA oracle?

Tags: oracle, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

A previous project with JPA Eclipse2.5 and Oracle database and glassfish4.0 Application server. i just want to generate the database by metadata. but it will generate the view pojo(previous project manager arraged a pojo with @Entity for every view which created in oracle ) to table .  Now , I just want to generate all the tables by metadata. The persistense.xml just like this:

```
    <property   name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"  value="create" /> 
    <property   name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source"    value="metadata-then-script" /> 
    <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source" value="META-INF/sql/create1.sql" />
```

in create1.sql just want to drop the **needlessness** tables:

```
begin
    for table_record in (select table_name from user_tables where table_name like 'V_%')
    loop
        execute immediate 'DROP TABLE ' || table_record.table_name ;
        dbms_output.put_line('Table ' ||  table_record.table_name  || ' dropped' );
    end loop;
end;
```

but it dose not work.  the log report:

```
Local Exception Stack:
```

Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: ֚ 1 ѐ, ֚ 101 : 
PLS-00103: ԶЖػۅ "end-of-file"՚ѨҪЂ֮һʱú
 ( begin case
   declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return
   select update while with 
     <<
   continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge

```
Error Code: 6550
Call: begin     for table_record in (select table_name from user_tables where table_name like 'V_%')   loop
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="begin     for table_record in (select table_name from user_tables where table_name like 'V_%')   loop")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
```

Answer (score 0):

To drop bound integrity constraints, you must add it to sql **cascade constraints**.

```
  begin
        for table_record in (select table_name from user_tables where table_name like 'V_%')
        loop
            execute immediate 'DROP TABLE ' || table_record.table_name ||' cascade constraints ';                
        end loop;
    end;
```

Comment: the tables hav'nt any constraint with them, because all of them are created from POJOs in which haven't any one to one or one to many relationships.

Comment: I guess  the eclipselink JPA dose not regard the sqls as standard sql.

Comment: To diagnose an error, you must add exception handling. Most likely the tables can not be deleted by the fact that SQL cursors are open with these tables and there are locks to delete the table. You need to close the application using these tables and delete the tables in sqlplus or sql developer or TOAD.

Comment: begin
    for table_record in (select table_name from user_tables where table_name like 'V_%')
    loop
        execute immediate 'DROP TABLE ' || table_record.table_name ;
        dbms_output.put_line('Table ' ||  table_record.table_name  || ' dropped' );
    end loop;
    exception
     when  OTHERS then 
    dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE || ':' || SQLERRM);
    end;

Comment: One of the problems is that the eclipselink JPA dose not support multiline sql statements.

Comment: call the stored procedure in one line.

Answer (score 0):

To diagnose an error, you must add exception handling. Most likely the tables can not be deleted by the fact that SQL cursors are open with these tables and there are locks to delete the table. You need to close the application using these tables and delete the tables in sqlplus or sql developer or TOAD
Example.
If another session uses a table, and we drop it, we get error number ORA-00054.

```
begin
    for table_record in (select table_name from user_tables where table_name like 'TEST1%')
    loop
        execute immediate 'DROP TABLE ' || table_record.table_name ;
        dbms_output.put_line('Table ' ||  table_record.table_name  || ' dropped' );
    end loop;
    exception
     when  OTHERS then 
    dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE || ':' || SQLERRM);
    end;

ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified
```

To call sql on a row, you need to make a stored procedure, and call the stored procedure in one line.

```
create or replace procedure DROP_TABLES_V IS 
begin
    for table_record in (select table_name from user_tables where table_name like 'TEST1%')
    loop
        execute immediate 'DROP TABLE ' || table_record.table_name ;
        dbms_output.put_line('Table ' ||  table_record.table_name  || ' dropped' );
    end loop;
    exception
     when  OTHERS then 
    dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE || ':' || SQLERRM);

end;
```

call the stored procedure in one line.

```
begin     DROP_TABLES_V;    end;
```